# Configure Website Names on LLighttpd Alpine Linux

Tags: lighttpd, domain-name, alpine

It has been a long time since I have done any hosting on Linux, and it that was on CentOS and Apache.  I am working on creating some sites on an Alpine server running Lighttpd.  Reviewing  the config file for Adminer, I could add my sites as a generic folder.  However, I would rather set them up with specific domains/subdomains.  Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on pointing a routed domain name to a specific folder.  Can anyone point me to an example or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.lighttpd.net/

[server.document-root](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Server_document-rootDetails)

`server.document-root = "/path/to/docroot"`

Comment: @DaveM: a primary source is a primary source is a primary source, and the question asked for a pointer to the documentation: "Can anyone point me to an example or documentation?"  I provided both a (simple) example and a pointer to the documentation.    Also, ServerFault is not a primary source.